# MySQL: TEXT and VARCHAR Speed and Size

Tags: mysql

Does varchar and Text affect the database size?
Also, do they differ in speed?

I have a Database that will have at least 4000 to 8000 new rows per day.
I'm quite worried about how it performs. This is my first time setting up an Enterprise-grade system and database though.

Comment: With TEXT fields you can run into this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Answer (score 3):

Use what you need and don't worry about performance.  But use only what you need.  There are minor inefficiencies in saying `TEXT` when `VARCHAR(255)` will suffice.  Ditto for `VARCHAR(255)` when `VARCHAR(20)` will suffice.

Here's why:  If a `SELECT` needs build a tmp table (eg, for `ORDER BY`), it first tries to use a `MEMORY` tmp table (better), but may have to fall back on a `MyISAM` table (slower).  Any kind of `TEXT` or `BLOB` forces `MyISAM`.  `VARCHAR` turns into `CHAR` (for the tmp table); if the tmp table gets too big for `MEMORY`, it converts to `MyISAM`.

`TINYTEXT` is probably never a good idea.

A related issue:  `CHAR(...)` is useful *only* if the field is (1) constant length, and (2) declared with the appropriate `CHARACTER SET`.  A common mistake is putting a fixed-length hex string in a utf8 CHAR field.

`VARCHAR` and `TEXT` (all sizes) have a small length field prefixing them.  This is relatively insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `text` is appropriate for the huge content items such as blog post, since it is capped at `65,535 bytes` and `varchar` for a teaser, since it is normally capped at `255 bytes`.